# Country-select throws ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need a country selector.  Rails' site writes that they removed their country selector helper so as not to offend people. I installed the country-select gem. It installed fine, but when I call it like so:

```
f.country_select("country")
```

or like so:

```
f.country_select(:country)
```

where `f` is my `FormBuilder` object, it throws an `ArgumentError`

```
wrong number of arguments(4 for 0)
```

The docs say it only requires one argument. What gives this? And what does `4 for 0` mean?

EDIT:
Here's the Full error stack:

```
country-select (1.1.1) lib/country-select.rb:7:in `initialize'
country-select (1.1.1) lib/country-select.rb:7:in `new'
country-select (1.1.1) lib/country-select.rb:7:in `country_select'
country-select (1.1.1) lib/country-select.rb:93:in `country_select'
app/views/admin_area/new_user.html.erb:15:in `block in _app_views_admin_area_new_user_html_erb__169470495_30991140'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:435:in `form_for'
app/views/admin_area/new_user.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_admin_area_new_user_html_erb__169470495_30991140'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:48:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:56:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.0.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__836640127__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__1017747328__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.1) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Here's where I'm calling it:

```
    <div id="new_user_form">
  <%= form_for(:user, :url => {:action =>'create_user'}) do |f| %>
       <table>
         <tr><td><%= f.label(:username, 'Enter a Username:') %> </td>
     <td><%= f.text_field(:username) %></td> </tr>
     <tr><td> <%= f.label(:password, 'Enter a Password:') %></td>
      <td><%= f.password_field(:password) %></td></tr>
      <tr><td><%= f.label(:confirm, 'Confirm your password:') %></td>
      <td><%= f.password_field(:confirm) %></td></tr>
     <tr><td> <%= f.label(:email, 'Enter your e-mail address:') %></td>
     <td> <%= f.text_field(:email) %></td></tr>
      <tr><td><%= f.label(:username, 'City:') %></td>
      <td><%= f.text_field(:city) %></td></tr>
      <tr><td><%= f.label(:country, 'Country:') %></td>
      <td><%= f.country_select(:country) %></td></tr>
    <tr> <td> <%= f.label(:firstname, 'First Name:') %></td>
    <td>  <%= f.text_field(:firstname) %></td></tr>
      <tr><td><%= f.label(:lastname, 'Last Name:') %></td>
      <td><%= f.text_field(:lastname) %></td></tr>
      <tr><td><%= f.submit('Submit') %></td><td></td></tr>
       </table>
      <% end  %>
</div>
```

(It's still a work in process, btw)

Here's the country-select.rb (not my code)

```
# CountrySelect
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module FormOptionsHelper
      # Return select and option tags for the given object and method, using country_options_for_select to generate the list of option tags.
      def country_select(object, method, priority_countries = nil, options = {}, html_options = {})
        InstanceTag.new(object, method, self, options.delete(:object)).to_country_select_tag(priority_countries, options, html_options)
      end
      # Returns a string of option tags for pretty much any country in the world. Supply a country name as +selected+ to
      # have it marked as the selected option tag. You can also supply an array of countries as +priority_countries+, so
      # that they will be listed above the rest of the (long) list.
      #
      # NOTE: Only the option tags are returned, you have to wrap this call in a regular HTML select tag.
      def country_options_for_select(selected = nil, priority_countries = nil)
        country_options = ""

        if priority_countries
          if (unlisted = priority_countries - COUNTRIES).any?
            raise RuntimeError.new("Supplied priority countries are not in the main list: #{unlisted}")
          end
          country_options += options_for_select(priority_countries, selected)
          country_options += "<option value=\"\" disabled=\"disabled\">-------------</option>\n"

          # prevents selected from being included twice in the HTML which causes
          # some browsers to select the second selected option (not priority)
          # which makes it harder to select an alternative priority country
          selected = nil if priority_countries.include?(selected)
        end

        country_options = country_options.html_safe if country_options.respond_to?(:html_safe)

        return country_options + options_for_select(COUNTRIES, selected)
      end

      # All the countries included in the country_options output.
      COUNTRIES = ["Afghanistan", "Aland Islands", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola",
        "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua And Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria",
        "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin",
        "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia, Plurinational State of", "Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba", "Bosnia and Herzegovina",
                "Botswana", "Bouvet Island", "Brazil",
        "British Indian Ocean Territory", "Brunei Darussalam", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cambodia",
        "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China",
        "Christmas Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo",
        "Congo, the Democratic Republic of the", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cuba",
        "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt",
        "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)",
        "Faroe Islands", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "French Guiana", "French Polynesia",
        "French Southern Territories", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greece",
                "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guernsey", "Guinea",
        "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Heard Island and McDonald Islands", "Holy See (Vatican City State)",
        "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran, Islamic Republic of", "Iraq",
        "Ireland", "Isle of Man", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jersey", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya",
        "Kiribati", "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of", "Korea, Republic of", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan",
        "Lao People's Democratic Republic", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya",
        "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macao", "Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic Of",
        "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands", "Martinique",
        "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia, Federated States of", "Moldova, Republic of",
        "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nauru",
        "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger",
        "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "Northern Mariana Islands", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau",
        "Palestinian Territory, Occupied", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines",
        "Pitcairn", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Reunion", "Romania", "Russian Federation",
        "Rwanda", "Saint Barthelemy", "Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia",
        "Saint Martin (French Part)", "Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Samoa", "San Marino",
        "Sao Tome and Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore",
        "Sint Maarten (Dutch Part)", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa",
        "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "South Sudan", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname",
        "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic",
        "Taiwan, Province of China", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania, United Republic of", "Thailand", "Timor-Leste",
        "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan",
        "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Tuvalu", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom",
        "United States", "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu",
                "Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of", "Viet Nam", "Virgin Islands, British", "Virgin Islands, U.S.",
                "Wallis and Futuna", "Western Sahara", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"] unless const_defined?("COUNTRIES")
    end

    class InstanceTag
      def to_country_select_tag(priority_countries, options, html_options)
        html_options = html_options.stringify_keys
        add_default_name_and_id(html_options)
        value = value(object)
        content_tag("select",
          add_options(
            country_options_for_select(value, priority_countries),
            options, value
          ), html_options
        )
      end
    end

    class FormBuilder
      def country_select(method, priority_countries = nil, options = {}, html_options = {})
        @template.country_select(@object_name, method, priority_countries, options.merge(:object => @object), html_options)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please paste full error stack.

Comment: ...and  `new_user.html.erb`

Comment: The error seems to be in gem. Did it ever work?

Comment: It hasn't worked for me, but I spent a ton of time googling around for this error and as far as I can tell I'm the only one experiencing it.

Comment: I have this problem from time to time and I always forget that the working gem is called `country_select` and not `country-select`. Hope it helps someone :)

Comment: OMG @MirkoAkkov you are the bomb! `country-select` is the one recommended by active admin, but that doesnt work.. `country_select` works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the version of the country_select gem.  It appears that it was updated fairly recently to be compliant with changes introduced in Rails 4.x.  You'll want v1.1.1 or above.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I do already have version 1.1.1.  However, it seems that you're right about incompatibility with rails 4.x--the gem's code relies on the InstanceTag class which no longer exists in Rails 4.0 -- it's been replaced by a module called ActiveModelInstanceTag.  Is it by any chance a simple matter to fix this?

Comment: Honestly I didn't look _too_ closely at the nature of the changes.  I see that it's been bumped three times since 1.1.1 so unless you've got a compelling reason to stick with that version I'd jump to ~>1.2.0.  The code in that version of the branch takes into account ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag as well as the older InstanceTag (not namespaced) and a default, internal option.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! For some reason when I did a "gem install" for the gem it grabbed version 1.1.1 and when I typed "gem install country_select -v '1.2.0' it couldn't find it.  I had to Google for it and manually install it, but in the end it WORKED! Thanks again!

Comment: For anyone stumbing on this... there are two gems out there: `country-select` and `country_select`. If you install the one with the hyphen (which has a version 1.1.1) then you'll get this error. You need the one with the underscore (which, at time of writing, is at version 2.5.2) by Stefan Penner: `gem ' country_select'`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately documentation on this is somewhat sparse.
When your `country_select` is inside a form (i.e. you are using `f.country_select`...) you do not need to supply the `object` since you already have `form_for(object)`.

I am successfully using the following syntax with Rails 3.2.17 and country_select 1.1.3:

```
form_for(myobject) do |f|
  ...
  f.country_select "country", ["Australia", "New Zealand"], {}, {class: "form-control", id: "country"}
  ...
end
```

`"country"` is the attribute of the `myobject`, Australia and New Zealand are priority countries, the empty `{}` is options and the rest is html_options.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your view

istead of

```
f.country_select('country')
```

do

```
  country_select(:user, :country)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to install another gem to resolve the same error in Rails version 4.2.0:

`wrong number of arguments(4 for 0)`

The gem is specified as:

```
gem 'country_select', github: 'stefanpenner/country_select'
```

in your Gemfile, then run `bundle install` and restart the server. I found this solution [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3675).